# Calling a method individually by class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my blog I'm using Pico CMS, in the index.twig page I wrote this code that generates HTML with page title, description, and URL:

```
{% for page in pages|sort_by("time") %}
    {% if page.id starts with "blog/" %}
        <div class="post">
            <h3>
                <a class="page-title" href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
                <small class="date">{{ page.date }}</small>
            </h3>
            <p class="excerpt">{{ page.description }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

My idea was to make each title in a different color, I used [randomColor](https://github.com/davidmerfield/randomColor), and wrote this JavaScript:

```
$('.page-title').css('color', randomColor() );
```

But this makes all the page-titles in the page to be of same color, I would like each of them in a different color.
This is the website: [blog.lfoscari.com](http://blog.lfoscari.com)

Answer (score 3):

`$('.page-title').css('color', randomColor() );` in plain english is *Call the function `randomColor()` and get the colour and then set the same to **all** the elements matching the class.*

---

You've to use [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over all elements, get the random colour by calling the function and set it to each element individually.

```
$('.page-title').each(function() {
    $(this).css('color', randomColor())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`css()` with callback](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function)** , it will iterate over elements and you can update value by returning

```js
$('.page-title').css("color", randomColor);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/randomcolor/0.4.4/randomColor.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-title">1</div>
<div class="page-title">1</div>
<div class="page-title">1</div>
<div class="page-title">1</div>
<div class="page-title">1</div>
<div class="page-title">1</div>
```

Comment: `$('.page-title').css("color", randomColor);` will also do.

Answer (score 0):

Twig has a [random function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/functions/random.html) that you can use:

```
<a class="page-title" 
   style="color: {{ random(['orange', 'pink', 'LightSkyBlue']) }}" 
   href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a>
```